# Dirichlet eigenvalue problem on the Hilbert cube

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve the Dirichlet problem for the Helmholtz equation 
\begin{aligned}-\triangle u & = & \lambda u, & x\in\Omega,\\
u & = & 0, & x\in\partial\Omega,
\end{aligned}

on the Hilbert cube $\Omega=\left(0,\pi\right)^{n}=\underbrace{\left(0,\pi\right)\times\cdots\times\left(0,\pi\right)}_{n\ \textrm{times}}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Namely, I'm looking to find an expression for $\lambda$.

I can get so far but then I get bogged down by indices and get confused about what to do next. Can anyone help? This is my attempt so far.

Separating the variables, we set 
$$
u\left(x_{1}x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right):=\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)
$$
 so that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\triangle u\left(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right) & = & X_{1}''\left(x_{1}\right)X_{2}\left(x_{2}\right)\ldots X_{n}\left(x_{n}\right)+X_{1}\left(x_{1}\right)X_{2}''\left(x_{2}\right)\ldots X_{n}\left(x_{n}\right)+\cdots+X_{1}\left(x_{1}\right)X_{2}\left(x_{2}\right)\ldots X_{n}''\left(x_{n}\right)\\
 & = & -\lambda u\left(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\\
 & = & -\lambda X_{1}\left(x_{1}\right)X_{2}\left(x_{2}\right)\ldots X_{n}\left(x_{n}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
We are looking for non-trivial solutions, so we are safe to divide
each side by $\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)$ to yield 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{X_{i}''\left(x_{i}\right)}{X_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)}=-\lambda.
$$
 Now each of the terms on the LHS is a function of a single variable,
independent of each of the other terms; hence 
$$
\frac{X_{i}''\left(x_{i}\right)}{X_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)}=c_{i}
$$
 for some constants $c_{i}$. Now $u$ must satisfy the boundary condition,
$u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Hence, for non-trivial solutions, we
have for each $i\in\left[1:n\right]$, 
$$
X_{i}\left(0\right)=0=X_{i}\left(\pi\right).
$$
Hence for each $i\in\left[1:n\right]$, we must solve the system 
$$
\begin{cases}
X_{i}''\left(x_{i}\right)-c_{i}X_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)=0, & x_{i}\in\left(0,\pi\right),\\
X_{i}\left(0\right)=0=X_{i}\left(\pi\right).
\end{cases}
$$

Now this is just a Sturm-Liouville system, so doing the usual separation of variables again, we find that $c_i > 0$ and

$$
c_{i}=\left(\frac{n_{i}\pi}{\pi}\right)^{2}=n_{i}^{2},\ n_{i}\in\mathbb{N}.
$$

I'm not absolutely sure about the last assertion. I feel that it should be something like

$$
c_{i,i_j} = \left(\frac{n_{i,i_j}\pi}{\pi}\right)^{2}=n_{i,i_j}^{2},\ n_{i_j}\in\mathbb{N}
$$

because for each fixed $i$, we have a set of solutions $c_i$ indexed by the natural numbers, and "the $n$'s aren't the same for each $c_i$" (I'm finding it difficult to explain what I think I mean).

Can anyone clear the fog, help me out a bit with the notation and show me how to proceed from here?

Edit: This is what I know I should be concluding, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Thus the mutually-orthogonal eigenfunctions can be described by the
multiply-indexed family of products 
$$
u_{k}\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sin k_{j}x_{j}
$$
 where $k=\left(k_{1},\ldots,k_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{n}$, and
with corresponding eigenvalues 
$$
\lambda_{k}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{j}^{2}.
$$

Comment: Consider a model eigenfunction, say, one that is $u(X) = \cos (m_1 x_1) \cos(m_2 x_2) \ldots \cos (m_n)$. The eigenvalue corresponding to this function is $\lambda = \sum m_i^2$.